# Random Forest Classifier giving 100% accuracy on the test split

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

While training the model I got:
Random Forest Classifier: 78%
SVC: 65%

But while testing the model i got:
Random Forest Classifier: 100%
SVC: 72%

```
x_status = train_path.drop(['Loan_Status'],axis=1)
y_status = train_path['Loan_Status']
x_status.shape,y_status.shape
  
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_status, y_status, test_size=0.4,random_state=42)
x_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape

def clf(model_clf,x_status, y_status,x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test):
    model_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_train_pred = model_clf.predict(x_test)
    y_test_pred= model_clf.predict(x_train)
    
    class_train_rep = classification_report(y_test,y_train_pred)
    print("Train:","\n",class_train_rep)
    
    class_test_rep = classification_report(y_train,y_test_pred)
    print("Test:","\n",class_test_rep)
```

Shape:
x_train (368, 11)
x_test (246, 11)
y_train (368,)
y_test (246,))

Classification Report:
Random Forest:

```
Train: 
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.82      0.47      0.60        85
           1       0.77      0.94      0.85       161

    accuracy                           0.78       246
   macro avg       0.79      0.71      0.72       246
weighted avg       0.79      0.78      0.76       246

Test: 
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00       107
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00       261

    accuracy                           1.00       368
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       368
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       368
```

SVC:

```
Train: 
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.00      0.00      0.00        85
           1       0.65      0.99      0.79       161

    accuracy                           0.65       246
   macro avg       0.33      0.50      0.39       246
weighted avg       0.43      0.65      0.52       246

Test: 
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      0.03      0.05       107
           1       0.72      1.00      0.83       261

    accuracy                           0.72       368
   macro avg       0.86      0.51      0.44       368
weighted avg       0.80      0.72      0.61       368
```

Is it alright if the test_split is 100% accuracy

Comment: I mean it's likely a mistake - so unless the data is very simply distributed, linearly or so - or maybe the test sample is so low (maybe 5, and it happens to get all 5) it should be investigated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you switched between train and test here

```
y_train_pred = model_clf.predict(x_test)
y_test_pred= model_clf.predict(x_train)
```

So what you really got is 100% accuracy on the train and 78% accuracy on the test, meaning your model is overfitting to the train.

Comment: ok, it did you mentioned and re-ran it. I got 100% accuracy again so it seems like it's a problem of overfitting. Thnx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You made typo on two occasions. First, when getting the predictions:

```
y_train_pred = model_clf.predict(x_test)
y_test_pred= model_clf.predict(x_train)
```

which needs to be replaced by:

```
y_train_pred = model_clf.predict(x_train)
y_test_pred= model_clf.predict(x_test)
```

Second, when calculating the classification report:

```
class_train_rep = classification_report(y_test,y_train_pred)
print("Train:","\n",class_train_rep)

class_test_rep = classification_report(y_train,y_test_pred)
print("Test:","\n",class_test_rep)
```

which needs to be replaced by:

```
class_train_rep = classification_report(y_train, y_train_pred)
print("Train:","\n",class_train_rep)

class_test_rep = classification_report(y_test, y_test_pred)
print("Test:","\n",class_test_rep)
```

As @Miriam Farber pointed out, both the 100% and 72% accuracy from the models are your training accuracy.